# datatable sorting in iron python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

I have a dtdtable in iron python

```
 dttable = handler.GetDataTable();
```

I tired to create a dataview for the above table by

```
 v=dttable.defaultview
```

so how do i sort this dttable using iron python ?

Answer (score 0):

```
dv = dttable.DefaultView
dv.Sort="TOP ASC"
dttable = dv.ToTable()
```

I used the above lines to sort a data table in iron python and It worked fine ."Top" is the column name , and ASC is to sort the table in ascending order